# React Bootstrap Table2 sorting and search

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using **React-Bootstrap-Table-2** for developing table displaying and etc
So today I already successfully added the table into my code, now I would like to add two features both sorting and search function on top of the table header

My code as follow:

```
render() {

    const colStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#6c757d',
      color: '#ffffff',
      width: '100px'
    }

// *what should I add here for search and sorting?


const columns = [{
  dataField: 'ProductID',
  text: 'ProductID',
  headerStyle: colStyle
}, {
  dataField: 'ProductName',
  text: 'ProductName',
  headerStyle: colStyle
}, {
  dataField: 'ProductPrice',
  text: 'ProductPrice',
  headerStyle: colStyle
}];
const {
  filter,data
} = this.state;
```

I try to work around on my columns by:

```
const columns = [{
      dataField: 'ProductID',
      text: 'ProductID',
      sort: true
      headerStyle: colStyle
    },
```

adding `sort: true`, well at least it was clickable, but it seems like it don't have any sorting action

As for the *Search function*, is it correct if I added to above code location?

The example image for my output: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the both parameters in the columns array :

```
const columns = [{
  dataField: 'ProductID',
  text: 'ProductID',
  headerStyle: colStyle,
  sort: true,
  filter: numberFilter(),
  headerSortingStyle
}, {
  dataField: 'ProductName',
  text: 'ProductName',
  headerStyle: colStyle,
  filter: textFilter(),
  sort : true,
  headerSortingStyle
}, {
  dataField: 'ProductPrice',
  text: 'ProductPrice',
  headerStyle: colStyle
  sort: true,
  filter: numberFilter(),
  headerSortingStyle
}];

////

<BootstrapTable
   keyField='id' 
   data={ this.state.missions } 
   columns={ this.state.tableColumn } 
   filter={ filterFactory() } 
   pagination={ paginationFactory(this.state.paginationOption) } 
   defaultSortDirection="asc"
   sort={ {
       //I did this to save the previous sort in the state
       dataField: this.state.filter.field,
       order: this.state.filter.order
   }}
/>
```

After, it can happens that the value you stored isn't understand by the sort function. So you can add a shortValue in you columns parameter :

```
   sortValue: (cell, row) => methodToHaveRightValue()
```

Example : [StoryBookSortValueCustom](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Sort%20Table&selectedStory=Custom%20Sort%20Value&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)